# Change of employer on type D visa while you are already in Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card

I have moved to Germany and working with Company A but I have received another offer from Company B and I am more interested and aligned to join Company B.
Currently, I have a type D visa and want to shift to Company B but I cannot resign from Company A and take up the new job, as Company A will then withdraw my Visa and I will no longer be allowed to stay here since it is type D visa.
Now If I get a blue card visa from Company A and then resign and switch the employer to Company B it will take around a minimum of 7 to 8 months and by that time the Company B offer won't be valid anymore.
How should I go about it without having to travel back to my home country? Can I apply for a Blue card from Company B directly since I am in Germany?

Comment: Normally a D-Visa is valid for 3 months. After arrival you must report to the local Immigration Office, where a **residence permit** will be issued based on what is written in the **remarks** field (look for the **§** in the text) of the visa. That will determine which **type** of residence permit has been authorised by the local Immigration Office when the visa was issued. Any change of employer must be authorised by them **and** if the conditions for a Blue Card are fulfilled the residence permit type changed to a Blue Card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I see it is mentioned "Employment in accordance of ..... Stay allowed only as an Software Developer at COMPANY_A_NAME, self employment not allowed". Is there a possibility to change to Company B? where shall I visit for this? and any idea how long this process will take because my VISA is valid till Oct but my wife's visa is only valid till Jul 27, and we also have got an appointment for Blue card visa on July 29

Comment: Whats after 'in accordance to' §18 a or b ...f. AUFENTHG? That tells tou which type. **§ 18b Abs. 2 AufenthG** is a BlueCard. The employer can only be changed at the local Immigration office.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It is mentioned as "Employment in accordance with 618B para. 2P. 1 Stay allowed only as Software Developer at COMPANY_A_NAME, Self employment not allowed"

Comment: @MarkJohnson It is mentioned as "Employment in accordance with §18B para. 2P. 1 Stay allowed only as Software Developer at COMPANY_A_NAME, Self employment not allowed" it was not 6 it is §

Comment: That is a Blue-Card. After your arrival you should have gone to the local Immigration Office to get a **residence permit** card. The visa itsself is normally only valid for 3 months. Have you done this? That is where you must now go with the job offer, where they will check if fulfills the conditions of a Blue-Card and if yes, you can take that job.

Comment: I have the same situation. How did you solve it? Regards,
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally a D-Visa is valid for 3 months.

After arrival you must report to the local Immigration Office, where a **residence permit** card will be issued based on what is written in the remarks field (look for the § in the text) of the visa.

- **§ 18b Abs. 2 AufenthG** is a BlueCard.

That will determine which type of residence permit has been authorised by the local Immigration Office when the visa was issued.

With a Blue-Card, any change of employer must be authorised by the **local Immigration Office** where you live within the first 2 years

- In Berlin: [Employment - Change of employer - Services - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/en/)

You just go to the local Immigration Office with the job offer, where they will check if fulfills the conditions of a Blue-Card and if yes, you can take that job.

> also have got an appointment for Blue card visa on July 29

Then that is when you can show them the job offer.