# What is the process to convert a residence permit for work to a blue card?

Tags: germany, blue-card, work-permit

I currently work in Munich, and I moved here with a Type D visa for the purpose of work(contract for a year). I currently have an offer that will make me eligible for a blue card. What exactly is the process shifting to this and who do I have to inform once I have resigned from my current role?

Comment: Have your new signed work contract in hand, show it to the Ausländeramt, they will give you Blue card.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already in Germany with a German residence title, you can apply for the EU Blue Card at the immigration authority that is responsible for your place of residence.

Source: [The EU Blue Card FAQs](https://www.bamf.de/SiteGlobals/Forms/Suche/EN/Expertensuche_Formular.html?nn=285986&queryResultId=null&pageNo=0&cl2Categories_Bereich=migrationaufenthalt&pageLocale=en&cl2Categories_Typ=faq&cl2Categories_Themen=blauekarteeu&sortOrder=title_text_sort+asc) Federal Office
for Migration and Refugees https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/Migrathek/BlaueKarteEU/blauekarteeu

See also [Change of employer on type D visa while you are already in Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24363/change-of-employer-on-type-d-visa-while-you-are-already-in-germany)

Comment: Yes, I'm already in germany. And thank you for the links. :)