# Change of employer before applying for blue card

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card

I hold a blue card eligible visa (right now entry level D). The company for which I got this has been delaying my starting date ever since. Now I have received a new offer for another German company. I am planning to travel with my valid visa and change my employer before joining the first company. I wanted to understand if I can change my employer BEFORE applying for Blue card residence permit as I really don’t want to join the first company and then serve notice period and then change to the new company. Please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change of employer on type D visa while you are already in Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24363/change-of-employer-on-type-d-visa-while-you-are-already-in-germany)