# Change employer before receiving a blue card in Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card, residency

I currently have a visa type D valid for 1 year and am eligible for a blue card. However, I can apply for it no sooner than 2 months before the visa expires (it is stated on the site with appointments in Berlin). So the probation period (6 months) expires before the date of application.

The question is if I decided not to proceed with the company or if the company didn't want to employ me after the probation period ends can I find another job in Germany or I must leave the country?

I have checked this answer but it does not work in my case:
[Change of employer on type D visa while you are already in Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24363/change-of-employer-on-type-d-visa-while-you-are-already-in-germany)

Comment: What is written in the remarks portion of the visa? An image of the visa would be useful.

Comment: The following is written: 18.2 aufenthg software engin. {comany name} aufenthaltdauer entsprichtgültigkeit